# How can I select the last drop-down option in selenium with python?

Tags: python, select, selenium, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down menu as follows in HTML:

```
<select id="TargetRadius" name="TargetRadius">
    <option value="1" selected="true">1</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
</select>
```

I want to choose the last option.  However, I am looping this, and the values change for each loop.  How can I choose the last option without referencing the value of the "option" tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do so is:

```
from selenium import webdriver    

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('navigate to url')

select_elem = driver.find_element_by_id('TargetRadius')
select_elem.click()
options = select_elem.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
options[len(options)-1].click()
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work for you:

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("TargetRadius"))
selectLen = len(select.options)
select.select_by_index(selectLen-1)
```